# how to manage a state with akka streams using ttl

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to listen to sqs using akka streams and i get messages from it's q 
using this code snippet:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ConfigUtils.dtsConfiguration.ioThreadPoolSize))
val awsSqsClient: AmazonSQSAsync = AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder
  .standard()
  .withCredentials(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider())
  .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(sqsEndpoint, ConfigUtils.dtsConfiguration.regionName))
  .build()

val future = SqsSource(sqsEndpoint)(awsSqsClient)
  .takeWhile(_ => true)
  .mapAsync(parallelism = 2)(m => {
    val msgBody = SqsMessage.deserializeJson(m.getBody)
    msgBody match {
      case Right(body) =>  //for each stream add (body.ID,body.Record.FileContent) or concatenate the new fileContent
                           // with current map (of same id) 
                           // that for each key in the map - if the filecontent size > 100 kb remove the relevant tuple from 
                         the map and perform an operation on it 
    }
    Future(m, Ack())
  })
  .to(SqsAckSink(sqsEndpoint)(awsSqsClient))
  .run()
```

I've already commented the specific point in code i need to manipulate the stream.

what i need basically is for each record fetched from sqs to do this:

i want to put it's content into a Map[Int,String] that Int represent key, and the string is the record content.
(for other keys i will concatenate it's content till its size is greater than 1kb)

(this like saving a state per key).

then i want to do the following:

i want to perform an operation for each tuple (continually with a stream)
when it's content size > 1kb, and then remove it from the map.

i also need a ttl for those records that didn't updated for spacific peiod say 30 seconds in the map.

can it be done using akka streams also?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Flow.statefulMapConcat` is something of a swizz-army-knife that allows you to keep state and conditionally emit values downstream. If you are happy discarding the TTLs only when elements arrive this is also doable but having a tick triggering eviction is a little bit trickier and may be easier by implementing a custom `GraphStage` instead.

Here is a simplified example, that will accumulate values per key until a limit is reached and then emit downstream.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Iterable
val theThing: Flow[(String, Int), (String, Int), NotUsed] =
  Flow[(String, Int)]
    .statefulMapConcat { () =>
      // state kept in factory function scope
      var state = Map[String, Int]()

      // for each incoming tuple
      {
        case (key, value) =>
          val newValueForKey = state.getOrElse(key, 0)

          // ... evicting old elements could go here ...

          if (newValueForKey > 10) {
            // max size, emit something downstream
            state = state - key
            Iterable(key -> newValueForKey)
          } else {
            // just update state, don't emit anything
            state = state + (key -> newValueForKey)
            Iterable.empty
          }
      }
    }
```

To do the tick for this you would have to introduce a tick-element somehow, but that would possibly also be affected by back pressure, so that leads back to a custom GraphStage. GraphStages has a timer API that allows them to schedule ticks as a side channel not affected by back pressure. You can find details about how to implement such in this section of the Akka docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-customize.html#custom-linear-processing-stages-using-graphstage